# Отловить исключение при сохранении сущности, CrudRepository Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, repository, spring-data-jpa

Пытаюсь отловить исключение при попытке дублирования полей во время сохранения пользователя (на поле ограничение UNIQUE). Использую `save` от `CrudRepository`, в [документации](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html) следующее описание метода:

> Returns:
> the saved entity; will never be null.
> Throws:
> IllegalArgumentException - in case the given entity is null.

Но что если ошибка будет при выполнении запроса?

Контроллер:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/api/users/save")
public ResponseEntity save(@Valid @RequestBody User user) {
    User newUser = userService.save(user);
    log.info(newUser);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(newUser);
}
```

Сервис:

```
@Override
public User save(User user) {
    user.setId(userRepository.getLastId());
    user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
    User newUser = null;
    try {
        newUser = userRepository.save(user); // никаких исключений
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("CATCH STATEMENTS");
    } finally {
        log.info("FINALLY STATEMENTS");
    }
    return newUser;
}
```

Но при попытке сохранить пользователя я получаю ошибку:

```
ERROR 16228 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-00001: нарушено ограничение уникальности (STORM.USERS_EMAIL_UINDEX) 
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: нарушено ограничение уникальности (STORM.USERS_EMAIL_UINDEX)
```

Сервис возвращает мне пользователя при выполнении `save`, а при передаче запроса (?) выбрасывает ошибку. Где отловить исключение я уже отчаялась найти.

Кстати, еще я пробовала проверять статус ответа в фильтре, но до фильтра выполнение просто не доходит. Возможно у вас есть идеи, где бы я смогла отловить исключение, спасибо.

**#UPDATED**

При попытке отловить `RuntimeException` или `DataIntegrityViolationException` суть не меняется (

```
log.warn("Try to save user");
try {
    return userRepository.save(user);
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
    log.error("Failed to save user");
}
```

И вот результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Там же написано `нарушено ограничение уникальности (STORM.USERS_EMAIL_UINDEX)`. У вас есть ограничение на сущносте, судя по названию, связанным с его уникальным EMAIL.

Comment: @AlexKrass, да, и я хочу отловить это исключение, но не знаю где

Comment: @AlexKrass, это ограничение наложено на таблицу, все верно. Я специально отправляю запрос на сохранение пользователя с уже существующим email-ом. Чтобы отловить исключение и  вернуть сообщение, что email занят

Comment: @AlexKrass, но я не знаю, где его отловить, потому как сервис отрабатывает без ошибок

Comment: Могу предположить, что userRepository.save(user); может вернуть null или другую структуру, содержащую текст ошибки, и при вызове уже ResponseEntity.ok(newUser); получается сама ошибка (или её описание). Проверьте, что у вас лежит в newUser и оберните в try... catch... ResponseEntity.ok(newUser);

Comment: @AlexKrass,  спасибо, но userRepository.save(user) возвращает пользователя, если я вместо ResponseEntity.ok(newUser) возвращаю строку, то поведение не меняется

Comment: Хорошо, давайте решать проблему логически. Если закомментировать userRepository.save(user); ошибка проявляется? В теории его должен был отловить ваш метод catch и если он этого не делает, то это странно. Можно вырезать весь код и добавлять частями, начиная с того, что он возвращает строчку и дальше по нарастающей. Обычно это помогает локализовать ошибку в непонятных случаях.

Comment: @AlexKrass, в том и дело, что `catch` у меня не отрабатывает

Comment: @AlexKrass, сервис отрабатывает, возвращает пользователя и я его логирую. А дальше, при возвращении результата из контроллера, будь то `ResponseEntity` или обычная строка - ошибка

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116178/discussion-between-alex-krass-and-azlov).

Answer (score 1):

Вы не можете отловить, потому что там RuntimeException нужно ловить, а если конкретней, то DataIntegrityViolationException. Почитать можно например
[тут](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-dataIntegrityviolationexception)

Comment: Спасибо, но ведь RuntimeException подкласс Exception, я потому его и поставила, чтобы любые ошибки отловить. Также пробовала ваш метод, но ничего не изменилось (в вопросе я разместила пример).

Comment: А БД у вас какая? Я сейчас на h2/postgres попробовал, всё работает как ожидается, видимо проблема конкретно в работе драйверов самого вендора БД. Попробуйте другую БД, либо другую версию драйверов.

Comment: Используем Oracle

Comment: Либо как вариант может у вас есть Advice, который уже перехватывает такие вещи.

Comment: На Oracle тоже всё работает хорошо, меня смущает конкретно ошибка, у меня вылетает DataIntegrityViolationException, а у вас sqlintegrityconstraintviolationexception, чем/как вы к базе подключаетесь?

Comment: У меня есть только несколько фильтров, которые работают с куки и заголовками.   Контроллер отрабатывает нормально, но `response` в фильтре перехватить не могу, падает ошибка именно где-то здесь

Comment: Используем `spring-data`. Создали конфиг, в котором описали jpa-бины

Comment: а к Oracle подключаетесь через такую зависимость?

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        </dependency>

Comment: нет, `<groupId>com.oracle</groupId><artifactId>ojdbc6<.artifactId>`

Comment: Попробуйте перейти на новый, думаю это может помочь

Comment: Спасибо, попробуем